# Self and proc.call parameter

Tags: ruby, self

I know there are already a lot of questions about `self`, but I just wanted to make sure I've understood it.

```
def buttonPressed
    @action.call(self)
end
```

1. In this code, `self` refers to `@action` (because `@action` is the receiver of the call method). Is that right?

   ```
   { songList.start }
   ```
2. If the proc object has no parameters like in this case, why give `prc.call self` as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I. Outside of a class, `self` returns `main` of type `Object`.  Inside a class, it will return the current instance of the class.

II. In the case of this particular block, there is indeed no need for `self` to be passed, but passing `self` means you can also potentially have `action`s that can access `self`.

Comment: So [instance].buttonPressed is self and not @action?

Comment: @user1492818 `self` represents the instance of the class in which `buttonPressed` and `@action` are defined.  In the classic “Programming Ruby” example, this is the instance of `JukeboxButton` on which `buttonPressed` is called.